# Custom events in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Is it possible to create custom events in C++?  For example, say I have the variable X, and the variable Y.  Whenever X changes, I would like to execute a function that sets Y equal to 3X.  Is there a way to create such a trigger/event?  (triggers are common in some databases)

Answer (score 10):

This is basically an instance of the Observer pattern (as others have mentioned and linked). However, you can use template magic to render it a little more syntactically palettable. Consider something like...

```
template <typename T>
class Observable
{
  T underlying;

public:
  Observable<T>& operator=(const T &rhs) {
   underlying = rhs;
   fireObservers();

   return *this;
  }
  operator T() { return underlying; }

  void addObserver(ObsType obs) { ... }
  void fireObservers() { /* Pass every event handler a const & to this instance /* }
};
```

Then you can write...

```
Observable<int> x;
x.registerObserver(...);

x = 5;
int y = x;
```

What method you use to write your observer callback functions are entirely up to you; I suggest http://www.boost.org's function or functional modules (you can also use simple functors). I also caution you to be careful about this type of operator overloading. Whilst it can make certain coding styles clearer, reckless use an render something like

seemsLikeAnIntToMe = 10;

a *very* expensive operation, that might well explode, and cause debugging nightmares for years to come.

Comment: Great explanation! I've used boost in past projects and have always been happy with the results.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/signals.html) is another commonly used library you might come across to do Observer Pattern (aka Publish-Subscribe). Buyer beware here, I've heard its performance is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Think you should read a little about [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)), specifically the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Qt from [Trolltech](http://trolltech.com/) have implemented a nice solutions they call [Signals and Slots](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPhbgrApNx0).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Observer pattern

[code project example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CppEvents.aspx)

[wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware you can't do it with default variables, however if you wrote a class that took a callback function you could let other classes register that they want to be notified of any changes.