# How I can do an event in c++?

Tags: c++, events

Well, sorry if my english isn't very good, second, in c++ how i can make events?, is something that i can't find as much i searched, and i think that it could help me a lot to make me the things a little easier with the college.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Depends on your platform.  Are you talking about Linux?  Win32?  .NET?  Something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom events in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996/custom-events-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the type of "events" whereby clients can set up callbacks to themselves when things happen, check out the [Boost Signals2 Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

If you are looking for the Win32 "event" synchronization object, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686915(v=VS.85).aspx).

Also check out [Custom events in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996/custom-events-in-c).